# Disable "Sign into your account" in Git authenticating on Windows

Tags: git, authentication, windows-10, azure-devops, credentials

I recently installed Git for Windows/git-scm on a new computer with Windows 10, and have tried to set `credential.helper=wincred` like I'm used to. But whenever I communicate with a remote I am presented with a "Sign into your account" dialog (hosted inside git-credential-manager.exe) which seems to be the same HTML-based dialog pushed by Microsoft in Visual Studio when using TFS/Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online):

[Microsoft sign-in dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Florz.png)

How can I disable this dialog from ever presenting - it makes absolutely no sense to have slow dialog pop up with multiple steps to enter an email address, wait for a redirect, and then finally the password when I can do it in a blaze on the command prompt (and have the cred helper store it for subsequent authentications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are encountering is probably [Git Credential Manager for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) (GCM). GCM is being bundled with recent version of Git for Windows and get enabled by default during installation.

The `git config` for GCM is `credential.helper=manager` and if you ran the following command

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

you will probably see `credential.helper` set to manager and be able disable the same.

On the other comment about this not making sense, traditional `wincred` store is not capable of handling multi-factor authentication, which is very common (and recommended) for VSO/VSTS or GitHub. GCM's interactive dialog is designed to handle that (Internally, GCM still used Windows Credential Manager to store the token received).

Comment: Thank you for the deeper insight. What I don't understand is that `git config [--global] --list` does not reveal that this setting was indeed set inside the mingw64 folder, and actually honoured, even though it intuitively should not.

Comment: For Tortoise git I disabled this through the settings UI under Credentials setting Credentials Manager to None

Comment: To disable this run the following from an elevated command prompt (Windows key>cmd,right click cmd, run as administrator) or git bash prompt and then type:
git config --edit --system
then use the arrow keys to navigate to the line that says:
helper = manager
and delete it by pressing the d key twice. 
Then save the file by pressing escape, typing !wq and pressing enter.

Comment: @DickyMoore I think you meant :wq, not !wq.